# Persist SQLite Data upon application uninstall

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, ios5

We are storing a unique identifier for the mobile device in an SQLite database, to be used for licencing purposes. The problem is that if a user removes the application then reinstalls it again, the SQLite database is gone along with our stored variable.

How to prevent removing the databse upon application installation, so that we can reuse the database if the application was reinstalled again

Thanks

Comment: It's called SQLite, not SQLLite.

Answer (score 2):

You can approach this by sending the information to a server side, you can't store any data out side the application sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- Store the key on your own server
- Store the key in the device's keychain. Notice that you won't be able to remove the key from the user's keychain after the app has been removed from their device. More info about the keychain here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

In the program you can create a copy of the SQLite database. Simply drag and release the database into the program resources.